# Requiring any audio module in node.js hangs application

Tags: windows, node.js, audio

I'm writing a node.js script that will play an MP3 / WAV / anything based on a timer (e.g. an alarm clock). I'm noticing that when I require any kind of audio library in node.js (e.g. "player", "speaker", "play") the app doesn't actually start, nor does it crash.

This code works:

```
// var p = require("player").Player();
console.log("Hello World");
```

But when I uncomment the first line:

```
var p = require("player").Player();
console.log("Hello World");
```

Nothing happens. When I run `node index`the first time, I see "Hello World" as expected. But when I run it the second time, the app "runs" and stays running, but I see no output. I don't get an error, I don't get booted back to the command line, nothing.

> C:\Users\johnsmith\Documents\GitHub\testapp>node index
>
> _

Even when index.js is literally nothing but a require and a console.log, nothing happens. I'm able to include other modules (as I'm using 'cron' to run code periodically) but it's only audio-based modules that aren't working.

If I put the console.log first, then the require, I see the output, but as soon as it hits the require, it stops doing anything .

I'm running Windows 8.1, 64 bit, 16gb RAM, Intel i7-4770 (3.4GHz) with on-board audio. Disabling all but my HD audio device in device manager does nothing -- it's got me stumped. Any clues?

EDIT: I've tried running my code with and without elevated privileges and it's still the same.

EDIT 2: Here's the (partial, I can't redirect all npm output to a file?) output when I run `npm install player --save`: http://pastebin.com/eHHddicZ

Edit 3 & 4: This fails on my second Windows 8.1 machine (haven't tried my Raspberry Pi yet, which is my ultimate destination). Also, a try-catch on the `require()` returns no error, so there's nothing wrong with the module itself. The node_modules/player/bin contains one file -- "cli" (no extension) so I'm wondering if there needs to be more in here. Downloading mpg123 and placing all of the files in there does nothing. I'm stumped!

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue... Did you ever find the cause?

Comment: Sprinkling the file being required with log statements revealed it was going into an infinite loop, causing the behavior described in this question.

Comment: @StijndeWitt Interesting. Were you able to fix the issue? I gave up a while ago and switched to shelling out to mpg123 which actually worked more reliably than the "player" module I was trying to use (which would drop in and out if another process was trying to do something